# Route specific S3 hosted website path to EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I'm hosting my website files on a S3 bucket using the static website hosting feature, however; since my project is build under a framework that exports some API routes using relative paths, I run into the problem that those requests fail because S3 is not meant to serve those API requests.

My intended solution here was to create a Node server that runs on a container under a EC2 instance, and then have any requests made by the static website files to `domain.com/api` be served by this server on EC2.

For example, suppose my automatically generated static files are hosted on a bucket with the name `domain.com`, the user would then access this page and the static files will make a request **using relative path** to `/api/getSomeInfo`, the request URL will then be `domain.com/api/getSomeInfo`, in that case I would like to make that request to the node server running on EC2 and give back the response to the page that made the request.

How can this be accomplished?

I tried using the s3 static website routing rules, but that did not work.

This was the rule I tried:

```json
{
  "Condition": {
    "KeyPrefixEquals": "api/"
  },
  "Redirect": {
    "HostName": "ec2-domain.com", //Idealy I would like this to be the same domain. Eg. domain.com; In which case this rule wouldn't even be necessary
    "HttpRedirectCode": "301",
    "Protocol": "https",
    "ReplaceKeyPrefixWith": "api/"
  }
}
```

What I ended up doing was serving both the static files and the API routes using that node server running on EC2, but I would like to serve the static files using S3 and maybe CloudFront for performance reasons.

Thank you.

Comment: So basically do you need to serve your static files from S3 using the domain connected to S3?

Comment: Right @DreamBold, and route requests made to /api/... to EC2. Do you have another suggestion? I'm open to it

Comment: Why don't you create a subdomain for S3 and associate it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using CloudFront, which supports [multiple sources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DownloadDistS3AndCustomOrigins.html) ("origins" in CloudFront-speak, like S3 and EC2) and path-specific configuration ("behaviours").

See the AWS Knowledge Center Article [Can I use a single CloudFront web distribution to serve content from multiple origins using multiple behaviors?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-distribution-serve-content/).  Spoiler alert: Yes.

Comment: Thanks @fedonev, I will give CloudFront a try and come back with the results.

Comment: Using CloudFront was indeed the solution, thank you!